# Odd Notepad++ Issue...Code Completely Replaced by NUL

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, notepad++, nul

I just had a really strange thing happen to me with Notepad++, and it could have been potentially devastating.

My entire JS/HTML5 file (~350 lines) was randomly replaced with NUL's.

All I know is that I saved my program, left Notepad++ going, and shut off my Surface Pro 1. I went into another classroom and turned it on again, a process taking maybe 3 minutes. This is also something I have done 1,000 times before. I turn on my tablet, enter my password, and am greeted not by my Checkers program (incomplete, obviously) but by a program consisting of one line and 9,986 NUL's in that line. The save option was grayed out, so I closed the file tab and reopened it from the directory it was in. Still NUL's.

I had a back-up, thank God and OneNote in Heaven, but I still lost an hour of work since making that back-up.

Anyone know what happened, so I can not have this happen when I don't have a back-up?

Comment: With "NUL's" you mean the Null character (0x00)? This is obviously a bug in either Notepad++ or the underlying OS...

Comment: Maybe your harddisk is failing? What ever the reason, you can never prevent this from happening; at some point software or hardware *will* fail. So always do those backups.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was just curious if it was something I did. Yeah, I had two back-ups actually, so we're good.